# sending data from client and receiving it on the server such that any client can access it in vanilla js

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if there was any way to set up a website such that you could send data from the client to a server (no libraries at all, even for the server) and store it there (in local storage: https://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_webstorage.asp) entirely in vanilla js.

Comment: Please add more details. Why can't you use any libraries? What constitutes a "library" exactly (do you need to write it in bare NodeJS without Express, or raw C or something)?

Comment: Essentially I want to be able to run this without any further setup on a different PC to the one I develop it on, and this PC would have neither node.js nor any other libraries. Therefore, I would prefer to write it not even in NodeJS, but just in javascript. I hope that clarifies it.

Comment: Thanks, but there's still at least a few fundamental misunderstandings here. JavaScript doesn't run anywhere but browsers. The whole point of NodeJS or another runtime is to run the Chrome v8 engine on a server. So without Node or another server-side JS runtime, JS cannot run. There is no such thing as "vanilla JS server/desktop".

Comment: Do you have any suggestions then as to how I could make something with those constraints? (or how to use Node without installing it on the second PC). Apologies if I am once again misunderstanding something.

Comment: You could write the server in a compiled language that's portable to both machines, say, Go or C. What operating system and sort of resources are available on the target PC and why can't you install anything on it? Work computer?

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. Could you point me to any resources for writing servers in C (or preferably C++). Yes it is a work computer, and the operating system of the target PC will be windows.

Comment: Maybe https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/cjj9t5/what_c_web_server_library_one_should_use_nowadays/, but in any case, the request is still too broad and off-topic to warrant answering here on SO. With the work computer running a server, I assume it's on a local network only? Strong [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676) vibe here--what are you really trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Alright thank you for your help. Yeah I was planning to host it with python HTTP on the local server. The goal is essentially to be able to make a working client-server communicating website and have it be portable enough such that all the contents fit in one email.

Comment: If you're trying to create a website on the internet, then I'd use a real web host rather than a random work computer. If you're trying to work on localhost or a local network, then this will work.

Comment: No, not a full website, just one that would temporarily run for devices on the same network. It would have very basic functionality too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[This](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp) article is about sending. I don't know why do you talk about the local storage.

Storing it involves the backend. You could learn Node.js (JS) or Flask (python) to do this.

If the server otherwise is not configured properly, it wouldn't allow to store the sent data permanently!